# Return Promise<String> from Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to return the myref as the promise as the reponse from this function to the calling end.Please help i am new at this.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require("firebase-admin"); 
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.createService = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
// Grab the text parameter.
const serviceName = req.query.serviceName;
const ttlHour = req.query.ttlHour;
const promise = [];
const myref = admin.database().ref("/root/events");
promise.push(myref);
// Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase 
Admin SDK.
myref.set({ name: serviceName, ttl: ttlHour, startTs: 0 }).then(snapshot => {
   res.send("Write succeeded!");
   });
});
```

Comment: *reponse from this function to the calling end* ... which one is *this function*. Can you elaborate more

Comment: createService is the function and i am calling it with the url and passing 2 parameters serviceName and ttlHour and wants to get the new push key genrated as the promise in the response @drinchev

Comment: createService is the cloud function for firebase @drinchev

Comment: Are you just looking to do `res.send(snapshot.key)`?

Comment: Thanks `res.send(snapshot.key)` works for me. but it would be prefect if i get that key as promise. @MichaelBleigh